# Run failed when programming in NetBeans with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans, mingw

I'm programming in NetBeans with the Qt Framework, using MinGW as toolchain. Most of the programs that I've written compile and run without any errors. But today I've tried writing a program that uses the QChart library and some other related libraries. Those libraries are a part of the Enterprise add-ons, so I had to specify those libraries to the linker. Now, my Code builds just fine but when I try to run it I get the error message: RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 216ms)
I did a lot of Research, but found nothing that could be of use to me. 
Here is my Code:

```
#include "QtWidgets/QApplication"
#include "QtWidgets/QMainWindow"
#include "QtCharts/QChart"
#include "QtCharts/QChartView"
#include "QtCharts/QLineSeries"
QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();

    series->append(0, 6);
    series->append(2, 4);
    series->append(3, 8);
    series->append(7, 4);
    series->append(10, 5);


    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    //chart->legend()->hide();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    //chart->createDefaultAxes();
    chart->setTitle("Simple line chart example");

    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    //chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    QMainWindow window;
    window.setCentralWidget(chartView);
    window.resize(400, 300);
    window.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

What could be the Problem?

Comment: By the way in my Code I used #include <QtWidgets/QApplication> instead of #include "QtWidgets/QApplication", but here I wrote it that way because StackOverflow could not Format my Code otherwise.

Comment: You can put the `<>` back in now as it is now formatted as code

Comment: run qmake. also block out the chart code to see if the bare app runs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried commenting out the parts with QChart and QChartView and it runs perfectly fine, which is not surprising. But how exactly do I run qmake? From the command prompt? Or from the internal terminal within NetBeans? And do I need to specify the library paths? Or just the Makefile path?